# Laravel 8 jetstream stack inertia. Redirect to Home after Login, instead of users choice

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

What happens to me is that if the user puts the url: project.test/med, the system redirects to Login but then it does not redirect to dashboard but to med. In RedirectIfAuthenticated the expression Auth::guard($guard)->check() is not evaluated or at least in the Log it is not shown, so I am not able to identify what is happening.

```
/** RedirectIfAuthenticated.php */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
       $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;
       Log::info($request);
       Log::info(Auth::user());
       foreach ($guards as $guard) {
         Log::info(Auth::guard($guard)->check());
         Log::info(Auth::check());
         if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
         }
      }
      Log::info(Auth::check());
      Log::info('end');
      return $next($request);
    }

    /** web.php */
     Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
         return Inertia\Inertia::render('Dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
    
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','verified'])->get('/med', function (Request $request) {
         return Inertia\Inertia::render('Med');
    })->name('med');
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel jetstream?

Comment: Yes, I have just edited the title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**: Fortify now ships with a simpler way of doing this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65462203/7884624) for simplified way.

---

The `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware does not do what you think it does. This middleware checks to see if a user is authenticated when trying to access a route with the `guest` middleware attached to it. So after you login to the application and you try to access `/login` route, this middleware will intercept the request and redirect the user to the `RouteServiceProvider::HOME` path.

---

With that being said, at the time of this writing, Laravel Fortify does not offer the ability to easily modify where the user gets redirected after registering or logging in to the application. [See issue for more info](https://github.com/laravel/fortify/issues/77)

To get this to work you will have to go through a few steps.

#### Step 1 - Create new LoginResponse class

Anywhere in your application create a `LoginResponse` class and implement `Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;

class LoginResponse implements LoginResponseContract
{

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? response()->json(['two_factor' => false])
            : redirect()->intended(config('fortify.home')); // This is the line you want to modify so the application behaves the way you want.
    }
}
```

#### Step 2 - Override the default Fortify Login Response

In this step you have to tell Laravel to use your login response instead of the default Fortify response.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;

class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            LoginResponseContract::class, // Contract is required in order to make this step work.
            LoginResponse::class,
        );
    }

    //...
}
```

Once you're done making the changes the user will be redirected to wherever you set it to be.

Comment: I get Target class [App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse] does not exist, any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: @GeorgeSharvadze If you did everything correctly and you're getting this error it may be that composer hasn't updated. just run `composer dump-autoload` and it will reload all classes.

Comment: @Raphael Cunha Thanks a lot for this. Do you also know how to redirect to another site after registration? I don't want to redirect to jetstream' s dashboard. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 12):

Go to ***config/fortify.php*** and modify this line:

```
'home' => RouteServiceProvider::HOME,
```

to:

```
'home' => function(){
    //if you want to go to a specific route
    return route('dashboard');
  
    //or if you have a bunch of redirection options
    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
       return route('admin.dashboard');
    }
    else{
       return route('guest.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some example of 'redirection options'? I can't get this to work

Comment: Following the same is causing  ```preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given``` in register route.

Answer (score 7):

There is a simpler solution to this.

If you look in `config/fortiy.php` you will see the home variable is set to:

```
'home' => RouteServiceProvider::HOME,
```

This refers to a public const variable in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

So to redirect users to the home page after they login you can simply change the home variable:

```
public const HOME = '/';
```

Doing it this way is slightly less complex and saves you having to create a whole new login response class.

If the changes don't take effect straight away try running:

```
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 3):

Just open fortify in the config folder

Search for 'home' => RouteServiceProvider::HOME

and replace it but your code logic and don't forget to add Auth facades

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

like is :

```
'home' => function () {
    $is_active = Auth::user()->is_active;
    $role = Auth::user()->role;
   
    if ($is_active == 1) {
        if ($role== 1) {
            return '/admin/dashboard';   
        } else {
            return '/';
        }
    } else {
        return '/login';
    }
},
```

Comment: Very good, simple and elegant solution instead of going through the hassle of creating a Response